# how i print without always save the document

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

i have office 2007 and every time i print a word file, it always asks me after that if i want to save the changes i've made. Understandable when i have made changes to the document. But the problem is that this happens even when **i don't** make changes. I just open the file and print it. why the "saving the file" question pops up? How can i stop that?

Thank you

Chrisa

Comment: I don't have a solution, hence only a comment, but I can explain *why*. When you go to print a document Word goes through it and updates all the automatically generated fields such as tables of contents, bookmarks and so on. As a result even though you have not changes anything Word itself *has* updated and changed the document and will want to save it. The same update will happen if you do a print preview without printing.

Comment: Are you sure you are printing on the physical printer and not on a PDF or XPS printer?

Comment: yes it's an EPSON printer